# Regular Expression capturing a group with ambiguous logical OR

Tags: python, regex

I have a situation, that simplifies to the following:

```
>>> print(re.findall(r'^[^=]+(!=|=)[^=]+$', "key!=value")[0])
=
```

However I'm trying to match "!=" instead. The regex engine shall see the "!" part of the group instead of the stuff before. I see that my expression is ambiguous, as it has two solutions one being the match done by the engine and the other one the one I desire it return instead.

I could exclude that character to be used before and afterwards, but **is there a way of telling the regex engine to prioritize a solution using the longest string in the group?**

Comment: Try with `r'^[^=!]+(!=|=)[^=]+$'`

Comment: It would be helpful if you would begin your question with a statement of what you are trying to achieve, possibly including an example that includes the desired result. As it is the reader is required to infer question #1 from your code and then infer question #2 from question #1 and "match '!=' instead" and then infer the actual question from the last sentence applied to question #2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your regex is too greedy:

```
r'^[^=]+(!=|=)[^=]'
```

The `[^=]+` is greedily matching beyond the '!' until it finds the '='.

It should be:

```
r'^[^=]+?(!=|=)[^=]'
```

Or:

```
r'^[^!=]+(!=|=)[^=]
```